# Error with GDataXMLDocument parsing

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, gdataxml

I want to access this xml page:

http://www.priorbank.by/CurratesExportXml.axd

I write:

```
NSArray *exchangeRateTableStringNodes = [document nodesForXPath:@"//LIST_R_DATE/R_DATE/LIST_E_CHANNEL/E_CHANNEL/LIST_RATE/RATE" error:nil];
```

But I get 115 wrong array items instead of three correct. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I have found is a splitting of this string into strings:

```
NSArray *exchangeRateTableStringNodes = [document nodesForXPath:@"//LIST_R_DATE/R_DATE/LIST_E_CHANNEL/E_CHANNEL/" error:nil];
NSMutableArray *exchangeRateTableStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *tempArr = [exchangeRateTableNode elementsForName:@"LIST_RATE"];
GDataXMLElement *tempElement = [tempArr objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *exchangeRateTableStringNodes = [tempElement elementsForName:@"RATE"];
```

But I still don't know why does it happen